# Trouble with javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am having trouble with my js.
This is the code: https://jsbin.com/legexep/1/edit?html,js,output
I'd like to get an alert box with the current number, not just to say: 'Hello'.
So if I click on 607 button, I'd like the alert box to say: '607' and so on.
Thank you for help.

```
item.addEventListener("click", function () {
alert('Hello');});
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/wehekimuvi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: please see example here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532312/creating-unique-id-buttons-in-a-javascript-loop

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Create a callback creator function to capture loop iteration variable:

```
function clickCallback(value) {
  return () => alert('Hello ' + value);
}
```

Use within `addEventListener`:

```
item.addEventListener('click', clickCallback(array[i]));
```

You can also use the event object received on the callback:

```
item.addEventListener('click', e => alert(e.target.innerText));
```

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
item.addEventlistener("click",function() {
    alert(mgk[i]);
}
```

Hopefully this solves it